# Passwordless SSH best practice

Tags: linux, ssh

I've found lots of articles describing how to do passwordless ssh and I have got it up and running no problems.

> What I can't find is information on how to best set this up for multiple machines?

If we have 100 servers that would all need to log into each other then I need to setup access to 99 other machines from all 100 machines. That 9,900 times I need to run the various commands. I could automate this but it still seams excessive to me.

> Is there a simple way for example where all machines have the same public/private keys and then it just works?

Ideally I would like to simply copy files onto each server and have it work.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have everyone access each other's machines?

Comment: The idea is that once someone has access to a certain account on any machine they have access to all. It's no different to using the same password on all 100 machines.

Comment: Question better suited to serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
1. Create a public and private key combination
2. Rename the file so that it does not interfere with the default keys on the machine
3. Copy these two files to all the host machines which you want to connect
4. use "$ ssh -i <path to the new public key>  user_name@host_ip"  command to login
```